# Django: Show progress on page for MySQL query?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have several queries that take a long time (about 3 seconds each) to execute so I can have the data in the context to show on a page for my website. Is there a way that I can show the page, then indicate which of the queries have finished, something like:

```
STARTED RUNNING QUERY 1
FINISHED RUNNING QUERY 1
*QUERY 1 RESULTS*
STARTED RUNNING QUERY 2
FINISHED RUNNING QUERY 2
*QUERY 2 RESULTS*
STARTED RUNNING QUERY 3
FINISHED RUNNING QUERY 3
*QUERY 3 RESULTS*
STARTED RUNNING QUERY 4
FINISHED RUNNING QUERY 4
*QUERY 4 RESULTS*
```

If relevant, here is my context:

```
context = {'avg': execute_query('usp_WeatherTempAccuracy', [service, 'avg', 1])[0],
           'first': execute_query('usp_WeatherTempAccuracy', [service, 'first', 1])[0],
           'last': execute_query('usp_WeatherTempAccuracy', [service, 'last', 1])[0],
           'decay': execute_query('usp_WeatherTempAccuracy', [service, 'decay', 1])[0]}
```

where `execute_query` executes a stored procedure with the given arguments.

Thanks.